# Codeigniter 3 routing error

Tags: codeigniter-3

I'm getting routing error on codeigniter 3.

Not Found
The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server. Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server

What I did.
My .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Also set `AllowOverride ALL`

My controller Test.php

```
class Test extends CI_Controller {
    public function index(){
        print_r('test');
        die();
    }
}
```

My route: `$route['test/(:any)'] = 'test/$1';`

And try to reach this page by url:

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/test/index.php
http://localhost/codeigniter/test/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this `.htaccess`**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|image|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

---

And if you are **accessing the controller** just type(assumed `codeigniter` as your project folder name)

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/test/
```

---

**What's the reason for this `$route['test/(:any)'] = 'test/$1';`?**

This nominate that there will be argument passed to this. it can be number or letter. Ex `http://localhost/codeigniter/test/aaa` or `http://localhost/codeigniter/test/25`

---

[Look at this](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your passing a uri(2), uri(2) is intended for the controller's method when your trying to use this route `codeigniter/test/1` you should specify your method first so it goes like this `$route['test/(any)'] = 'test/index/$i';` btw `codeigniter` is consider as your uri(0).